# i am getting this error in scenebuilder :com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon

Tags: javafx, netbeans

I drag and drop the icon from the container and set the property to PLAY_ARROW and I got error i.e., `class com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon` not exist.

```
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon ?>
```

and

```
<Icon accessibleRole="SLIDER" blendMode="SCREEN" cache="true" cacheHint="ROTATE" content="PLAY_ARROW" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="62.0" />
```

can any one solve this problem.

Comment: Are you creating a mobile app?

Comment: no ,i am designing a media player application with javafx, and i am unable to add icons to the frame

Comment: If you are not making a mobile application, don't use gluon controls.

Comment: Use fontawesomefx for icons.